# get all classes from css file (as text) using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a regex that will return all available classes from a css file. so far i have this:

```
/\.[\w-_]+[^\.\s\{#:\,;]/g
```

this works fine but it also captures some css rules. Example:

```
.sky-form .button {
    background-color: #2da5da;
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
```

it will return ".sky-form" ".button" and ".2s". how can I prevent the regex from returning anything from between the curly brackets?

### Edit - final answer

```
/(?:[\.]{1})([a-zA-Z_]+[\w-_]*)(?:[\s\.\{\>#\:]{1})/igm
```

the last part (?:[\s.{>#:]{1}) is to make sure its not capturing any image links like .png or part of paths like jquery.11.1.custom/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell it not to allow a digit as a first character after the initial period.

`\.[a-zA-Z_][\w-_]*[^\.\s\{#:\,;]`

The regex above allows for a class name that starts with a-z of both upper and lower case, or an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

```
/(\.[\w-_]+\s)/gmi
```

Should do the trick I think. https://regex101.com/r/zE8mM6/1